# How to upload image in codeigniter, Error Number: 1136

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

1. the controller
   i want user can upload image to my database in table "invoices" or "orders" for column "bukti_trnsfr"
   thanks

   ```
           public function payment_confirmation($invoice_id = 0 )
           {   
           $data['get_sitename'] = $this->model_settings->sitename_settings();
           $data['get_footer'] = $this->model_settings->footer_settings();
           $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
           $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
           $config['max_size'] = '100';
           $config['max_width']  = '1024';
           $config['max_height']  = '768';
           $this->load->library('upload', $config);
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_id_input','Invoice id','required|integer');
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount_input','Amount Transfered','required|integer');

           if($this->form_validation->run()    ==  FALSE)
           {
               if($this->input->post('invoice_id_input'))
               {
                   $data['invoice_id'] =set_value('invoice_id_input');
               }else{  
                       $data['invoice_id'] = $invoice_id;
                       $upload_image = $this->upload->data();
                       $data_invoices = array(
                       'bukti_trnsfr'  => $upload_image['file_name']);
                   }
               $this->load->view('customer/form_payment_confirmation',$data);
           }else{
                   $is_valid = $this->model_customer->mark_invoice_paid_confirmed(set_value('invoice_id_input'),set_value('amount_input'),set_value('file_name'));
                   if ($is_valid)
                   {
                           $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Terima Kasih, Produk Yang Anda Pesan Akan Segera Kami Proses');
                           redirect('customer/shopping_history');
                   }else{
                           $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Jumlah Nominal Salah, Silahkan Coba Lagi ');
                           redirect('customer/payment_confirmation/'.set_value('invoice_id_input'));
                       }

                }
       }
   ```
2. this is my model. 
                   **public function  mark_invoice_paid_confirmed($invoice_id,$amount,$bukti_trnsfr)
               {//check the invoice
                   $ret = TRUE ;
                   $data_invoices = $this->db->insert('invoices', $bukti_trnsfr);
                   $is_invoice = $this->db->where('id',$invoice_id)->limit(1)->get('invoices');
                   if($is_invoice->num_rows() == 0  )
                   {
                           $ret = $ret && FALSE;**

   ```
               }else{//check the amount



                       $total = $this->db->select('SUM(qty * price) AS total')
                                         ->where('invoice_id',$invoice_id)
                                         ->get('orders');                
                       if($total->row()->total > $amount )

                       {
                               $ret = $ret && FALSE ;
                       }else
                       {//mark the invoice to PAID
                               $this->db->where('id',$invoice_id)->update('invoices',array('status'=>'confirmed'));
                           }

                    }
               return $ret;
           }
   ```

Comment: It will be better to paste your code rather than an image.

Comment: What is `$ret = $ret && FALSE` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to upload image in your code. Use below mentioned lines to upload image in codeigniter after validation runs true.

```
$this->upload->do_upload('file_name');
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Error Number: 1136

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

INSERT INTO `invoices` () VALUES ('')

Comment: `var_dump($bukti_trnsfr);` and share output also share your table structure for `invoices` table.